# How to code Magento 2 enterprise's default pagebuilder as responsive (mobile friendly)?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, column, custom-column-grid, page-builder

As part of one of my Magento 2 enterprise projects, I need to enable the admin user to customize the page layout (responsive layout) using the page builder. For desktop, it could be done pretty well but there seems no solution on this for mobile devices.

I've been thinking of following approaches but do not find a code-level solution:

**1. Customize the page builder code and apply CSS classes instead of the inline CSS code, which applies at the moment.**

**2. Add some attribute for page builder's column component so that admin could modify the ordering and sizing for mobile too as it works for desktop.**

I do not find any relevant information on devdocs.magento.com either. If anyone could suggest some resources, it would be beneficial with the kind suggestions and solution if you have already implemented anything before.

Comment: Have you tested the default functionality? Your default should be mobile-ready and I am not sure how you are going to be able to program around the user.

Comment: @brentwpeterson I didn't find default as mobile responsive.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. It should be responsive by default. Did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with adaptation, I solved it by adding .column.main {width: 100%;}
You can also adjust the display breakpoints of the number of slides, you need to rewrite the file module-page-builder/etc/view.xml into your app module, create the same one with your breakpoints.